# Error Creating cluster in RabbitMQ on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, rabbitmq

I want to create a cluster of RabbitMQ on EC2. I have created an AMI of Ubantu and install the rabbitmq-server-2.3.1 on it.
I have also installed the management plugins for GUI. For cluster purpose I have also copied the .erlang.cookie file in another node.
My ploblem is when I am trying to connect with another node it gives me following error:

Error: {failed_to_cluster_with,['rabbit@ip-10-58-54-170'],
                               "Mnesia could not connect to some nodes."}

Anybody has any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Hi Anand, you should accept some of the answers to your previous questions, otherwise don't expect too many answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few usual causes for "Mnesia could not connect to some nodes":

- the nodes cannot actually communicate with each other (can you `ping` the other hosts?),
- Erlang restrictions prevent you from naming nodes in certain ways (e.g. FQDMs are not supported, the node name must be a single word) so you usually have to add the node addresses to your hosts file,
- the two nodes have different cookies (not the case here),
- Rabbit is not running on the remote node.

To quickly diagnose the issue:

- check connectivity:

  ping other_node
- check that Erlang can connect to other_node:

  erl -sname my_node -remsh rabbit@other_node
- check that Rabbit is running on the remote node:

  rabbitmqctl -n other_node status

Quite a few people have managed to get RabbitMQ clusters working on EC2, so it's certainly possible.

If you need more help, a great place to ask is the [RabbitMQ Discuss](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) mailing list.  The developers [make a point](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-August/thread.html) of answering the questions asked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case under Ubuntu 11.10 it helped to

```
#rabbitmqctl cluster MASTER SLAVE
#rabbitmqctl start_app
```

before I always got this error message...